# React.js + Router - Как сбилдить для размещения в папке?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, развертывание, react-router

Создаю админку для бота на React.js, и разместить в корневом каталоге не могу. Как сбилдить проект для использования в папке? Например https://domen.com/admin

Сам сайт запустился, но Router не видит ссылок. Они у меня /login, /users и т.д. А он наверное видит /admin/login ... Есть вариант настройки, который это пофиксит? Или нужно вручную прописывать пути с папкой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://scottvinkle.me/blogs/work/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory
Хорошая статья. Получилось даже лучше.